# Google Sheets V4 API error 400 INVALID_ARGUMENT

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm having a problem getting the JSON list of some very basic information I've put together in a google sheets file. I have ensured my API key is unrestricted and that the sheet itself is set to public,
I have also made sure that the google sheets API is enabled however I keep getting this error;

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Unable to parse range: TestingRealtimeData",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

The link to the original page is here;
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sT49JTaVGp5rt56A0hjs4WPVYDJDAMrjesqxU6RWrwo/edit#gid=0

And the published web page here;
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR3lrj8g2K6e47e3hTQmRkKiP5Q88yBGcqxO8YtaLH1pfOeHTg8wf4MtCnw_92TMizwHA68Xt1xu5PI/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true

Any idea what could be causing this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide your detail request for correctly replicating your current issue of `Unable to parse range: TestingRealtimeData`?

Comment: Can you please provide the API request you are sending?

Comment: Sorry if this isn't what you mean, I'm not an expert in this field; https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1sT49JTaVGp5rt56A0hjs4WPVYDJDAMrjesqxU6RWrwo/values/TestingRealtimeData?key=AIzaSyBxVIL2vNTX1JQjQCPnXZHNUgWFvQxzafI